# Trying to connect xmpp server by smack

Tags: android

I am using this code for connecting my android app to xmpp server i.e openfire Server with Smack api

```
public class MyXMPP {

private static final String DOMAIN = "nimbuzz.com";
private static final String HOST = "o.nimbuzz.com";
private static final int PORT = 5222;
private String userName ="";
private String passWord = "";
AbstractXMPPConnection connection ;
ChatManager chatmanager ;
Chat newChat;
XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
private boolean connected;
private boolean isToasted;
private boolean chat_created;
private boolean loggedin;


//Initialize
public void init(String userId,String pwd ) {
    Log.i("XMPP", "Initializing!");
    this.userName = userId;
    this.passWord = pwd;
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(userName, passWord);
    configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    configBuilder.setResource("Android");
    configBuilder.setServiceName("localhost");
    configBuilder.setHost("192.168.1.2");
    configBuilder.setPort(5222);
    //configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
    connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

}

// Disconnect Function
public void disconnectConnection(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }).start();
}

public void connectConnection()
{
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            // Create a connection
            try {
                connection.connect();
                login();
                connected = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            catch (SmackException e)
            {
              Log.v("errror",e.getMessage());

            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                                }

            return null;
        }
    };
    connectionThread.execute();
}


public void sendMsg() {
    if (connection.isConnected()== true) {
        // Assume we've created an XMPPConnection name "connection"._
        chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        newChat = chatmanager.createChat("concurer@nimbuzz.com");

        try {
            newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void login() {

    try {
        connection.login(userName, passWord);
        //Log.i("LOGIN", "Yey! We're connected to the Xmpp server!");

    } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}



//Connection Listener to check connection state
public class XMPPConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener {
    @Override
    public void connected(final XMPPConnection connection) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "Connected!");
        connected = true;
        if (!connection.isAuthenticated()) {
            login();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionCLosed!");
        connected = false;
        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionClosedOn Error!");
        connected = false;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "Reconnectingin " + arg0);

        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {



                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionFailed!");
        connected = false;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionSuccessful");
        connected = true;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0, boolean arg1) {
        Log.d("xmpp", "Authenticated!");
        loggedin = true;

        chat_created = false;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                }
            });
    }
}
```

}

but getting an exception i.e "The following addresses failed: '192.168.1.2:9090' failed because java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.2 (port 9090) after 30000ms".If i am missing something in my code please let me know.

Comment: Where is your Android app running?

Comment: I have a Client Server Environment.I have two machines one is Server Machine where I have installed (Openfire Server) And I am trying to connect it via client Machine i.e my phone.

Comment: Try the same ip:port using a browser on your phone.

Comment: Thanks it works now.But still I am unable to connect I am getting this exception now "No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 10000ms (~10s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.".

Comment: `Thanks it works now.But still I am unable to connect` ???? It works???

Comment: Means now I am able to open the IP:Port in my Phone's browser.But not able to connect and getting a different exception"No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 10000ms (~10s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'."

Comment: `Means now I am able to open the IP:Port in my Phone's browser.But not able to connect `. ????  If the browser cannot connect then i would say that i could not open ip:port in the browser. Very confusing talk you use. And for me it is the same timeout exception.